# want to read data from text file ,store it into Arraylist and convert it into integer ....data is in a single column

Tags: c#

> Error is An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
 ArrayList TargetOut = new ArrayList();
 ArrayList Desired_Output = new ArrayList();
 for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
 {
   string FileName2 = "E:\\Normalized_DesiredOutput.txt";
   FileStream FS2 = File.OpenRead(FileName2);
   StreamReader SR2 = new StreamReader(FS2);
   Desired_Output.Clear();
   while (SR2.Peek() > -1)
   {
     Desired_Output.Add(Convert.ToInt32(SR2.ReadLine())); //error
   }

   SR2.Close();
   FS2.Close();
}
```

I have also tried the code below but same error in converting string valuues into integer

```
 while (!SR.EndOfStream)
 {
    Line = SR.ReadLine().Split('\t'); 
    List<string> arr = new List<string>();
    arr.AddRange(Line);
    intList = arr.ConvertAll(s => Int32.Parse(s));  error
    myvalues.Add(intList);

 }
```

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your `Normalized_DesiredOutput` file? If it contains anything other than numbers, even white spaces, you'd run into issues.

Comment: I'd recommend A> debugging to find the value of `s` at time of exception, and B> Int32.TryParse()

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines(filename).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();` The framework is your friend.

Comment: @Will it still giving same error .    Normalized data consist of single column containing only numbers 2 , 3 ,4 ....error is specifically pointing int.Parse(x) with troubleshooting tip "whenconverting a string to DateTime, Parse the string to take the date before putting each value in DateTime object.

Comment: `int.Parse(x)` is throwing an error about "converting a string to DateTime?"  Yeah, I'm out.